# Must distinct tree eigenvalues be relatively far apart?

Tags: graph-theory, spectral-graph-theory

How close to each other can two distinct eigenvalues of a tree be, as a function of the number $n$ of nodes ?

For example, the path $P_n$ exhibits a gap of order $\frac{2\pi^2}{n^2}$ asymptotically as $n\to\infty$.

Following Aaron's suggestion, one may consider the tree on $n=4k-1$ formed by grafting together $4$ paths of respective lengths $k,k,k+1,k+1$. It is easy to see that $2\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{k-1}\right)$ and $2\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{k}\right)$ are eigenvalues, and the distance between them is of order $\Theta\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$ as $n\to\infty$.

Can the gap be significantly smaller, say exponentially small in $n$ ? 
Do we know anything on the trees that achieve the minimum ?

Comment: by an eigenvalue of a tree, do you mean an eigenvalue of the 0-1 adjacency matrix of an unweighted tree graph?

Comment: @guest: yes, I do!

Comment: You'd probably do better if there were no repeated eigenvalues. I'd look at a tree with one vertex of degree $3$ (i.e. $3$ paths with a common endpoint.) I'd guess that lengths nearly equal  (maybe $k-2,k,k+2?$ ) might be best among trees of this type. Ratio roughly  1:2:3 also seems worth a look. Maybe you can come up with a guess. If you delete a degree $1$ vertex to get a tree of the same type on $n-1$ vertices then the $n-1$ eigenvalues for that tree will interlace those of the big tree. There are three ways to do that. I'm not sure if it helps, but it might.

Comment: @AaronMeyerowitz: thanks ! Grafting paths together indeed improves the gap from $\Theta(n^{-2})$ to $\Theta(n^{-3})$. I edited the post accordingly.

Comment: There's a more general grafting operation (I've seen it a few places, and am not sure the original source): Given two trees $T_1$ and $T_2$, create a new tree formed by taking $2$ copies each of $T_1$ and $T_2$, together with a single additional vertex connected to all four trees (with the connection being to the same vertex in both copies of $T_1$ and the same vertex in both copies of $T_2$.  This new tree contains the spectrum of both $T_1$ and $T_2$ (e.g. if $v$ is an eigenvector of $T_1$, take the vector which is $v$ on one copy of $T_1$, $-v$ on the other copy, and $0$ elsewhere)...

Comment: ...So, up to constant factors, it's enough to just find two eigenvalues of different trees that are close together.  For example, an alternative way of getting $\Theta(n^{-3})$ is to apply this grafting to $P_{k+1}$ and $P_{k}$, getting a tree with both $2 \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{k}\right)$ and $2 \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{k-1}\right)$ as eigenvalues.

Comment: I'd think that having repeated eigenvalues would be a drawback but indeed this does seem better than k-1,k,k+1,k+2 or having three branches (based on a small number of cases)